# when exit and enter the app again using a MasterDetailPage, it crashes after a certain amount of times

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The first page of my app is a Contentpage where you login or MasterDetailPage if you are already logged in. Even when the app runs fine, if I exit tha app and enter a certain amount of times (sometimes is 2, sometimes even 10), the app crashes and I get the next error message. Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:  and this appears in crashlytics:

Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Fatal Exception: > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x249 (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{bbc6fff #0 id=0x249}
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

This only happens when I am in the masterdetailpage, in the login page functions very good

Comment: Does this exception point to some piece of code when it is thrown?

Comment: no, it doesn´t, all the elements of the master detail page since the master to the detail and app and mainpage doesn't show error

Comment: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { Application.Current.MainPage = maestro }); where maestro is the masterdetailpage, in this line fails sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I make a transition between 2 pages in the code too fast, so one of them didn't finish loading and the other was starting. That was the source of my error. Now that I fixed it I can see it in my emulator android 8.1, but have problems with 7.0 if I know why I will put it in the post.

EDIT:

The error in 7.1 is only when I am trying to installed it again in my phone with debug. The error is the next:

```
Android.View.WindowManager BadTokenException: Unable to add window token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?
```

if you use the app normally after the installation, it works good!